# Bernoulli distribution $p_n \to 0$. Does $B{_n}n$ converges in distribution to $0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_n=nB_n$ where $B_n$ is Bernoulli distributed with parameter $p_n \in (0,1) \forall n \in \mathbb N$. 
Let $p_n \to 0$. Does $X_n$ converges in distribution to $0$ ?

I think $X_n$ does not converges to $0$ in distribution, but I am not able to construct a counterexample. Does anyone know a counter example? Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F_n$ and $F$ be the CDF's of $X_n$ and $X = 0$, respectively. Then the set of discontinuity points is $D = \{0\}$. Showing convergence in distribution is equivalent to showing $F_n(x) \to F(x)$ for all $x \notin D$.

Clearly $F(x) = F_n(x) = 0$ for all $x < 0$. So suppose $x > 0$. Then 
\begin{align*}
F_n(x) = P(X_n \leq x) = P(nB_n \leq x) = P(B_n \leq x/n) = P(B_n = 0) = 1 - p_n \to 1 = F(x)
\end{align*}
since $p_n \to 0$.

So we actually do have $X_n \Rightarrow 0$ ($X_n$ converges to $0$ in distribution).

Comment: So if $X_n \to X$ in distribution, then $E(X_n) \to E(X)$ or $V(X_n) \to V(X)$ is true aswell?

Comment: No. Take $p_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: I do not see why this works, can you explain it?

Comment: If we take $p_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, then $EX_n = nEB_n = n \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to \infty$. But $X_n \to X = 0$ in distribution and the mean of $0$ is $0$, so $EX_n \not\to EX$ even though $X_n \to X$ in distribution.

Comment: $V(X_n) = n^2V(B_n) = n^2\cdot (EB_n^2 - (EB_n)^2) = n^2 \cdot (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{1}{n}) = n^{3/2} - n \to \infty$